# xargs line too long

Tags: xargs

I am trying to remove all files that have a hexadecimal digit in the first two digits, so I am using the following expression:

```
ls | grep -Z '^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]' | xargs -0 rm
```

However, the terminal outputs the error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

To double-check, I ran:

```
ls | grep -Z '^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]'
```

which outputs all of the files that I want to delete.

Why am I getting this error? 
Additionally, how can I delete these files?

Also, my file names are similar to the following:

```
ffc1abfa3149067e990620dbecfa96d325fbbd
ffcc72282168e33110ecf436e2726a5f901ca6
ffd010299a02ded0a8d41ee1ccc242f2193df2
ffd27295acbe3d35088a5a754f5593eac6a0ae
ffd332a39f7be05d58863fe3bf55d7aba68b69
ffd7ba85b0577b90c0fb1b3922303c486127d4
ffdb37718feaf64c404a6c2a3648f15cdf27b1
ffdbffe5b187c8a73d15da9e5f6cc0fb8d4df3
ffdd8c340650848759c7e59f90f8c112ac33ce
ffde57cb4ba9b69531a3b3f2c6588d2802f71b
ffdeb529353a85b642efa1404aa27e58982da1
ffe0bec99e3e64c61dd45e404c8ccf12d7bea5
ffe58837e9d976499781de17628f2f41e16c9a
ffee6887889924583762e43d5a6b9cd29b6690
fff0b6886aff6cb4073742fbf7bcc1b47d9b45
```

Perhaps the file names themselves are too long for `xargs`?

Comment: Try not using the `-0` switch. That worked for me. No spaces in my file names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Z` is to output a NUL after each file name with `grep -l`, not to change the newlines to NULs in the lines it outputs. So `xargs -0` sees only one huge record (with several newline characters in it) as there's no NUL delimited, so that's only one argument to pass to `rm` and it probably is bigger than the maximum size of an argument (128kB on Linux) and anyway there's no such file called `...ffd7ba85b0577b90c0fb1b3922303c486127d4<newline>...fff0b6886aff6cb4073742fbf7bcc1b47d9b45`.

Simply do:

```
rm [0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*
```

Or if the list is too big:

```
printf '%s\0' [0-9a-f][0-9a-f]* | xargs -r0 rm
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs        # best in ~/.zshrc
setopt extendedglob   # ditto

zargs [0-9a-f](#c2)* -- rm
```

Or with `ksh93`:

```
command -x rm {2}([0-9a-f])*
```

Or:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*' -exec rm {} +
```

Beware that in non-C locales `[a-f]` may match more than `[abcdef]`.

Comment: Only 5 solutions, pfft.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your selection of commands to something like:

```
 find . -name '^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

or another alternative

```
 find . -name '^[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: There's no point using the non-standard `-print0/xargs -0` over the standard `-exec {} +`. No point using `-exec rm {} \;` either as `rm` can take more than one argument. What goes after `-name` is a file name pattern, not a regexp. Some find implementations support a `-regex`, but the match is on the full path and is anchored already.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using just find. Something like `find -type f -iname '[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*' -delete` should do it. try first with -print instead of -delete to be sure, of course.

Comment: If you take a look at the accepted answer you'll see why this suggestion regarding `xargs` couldn't have worked.

Comment: Got it and removed it from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You may be running up against a file name limit depending on your file system type. See:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Specifically, the section on "Limits"

You can check your file system type if you dont know it using:

`$ cat /etc/fstab`